# Bash Script Regex match can't escape double quotes

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I tried different variations of trying to achieve the following but I just cannot.

```
#!/bin/bash

sb_command_passed=$*
regexMatch="^find every file matching '(.*)' in this folder and subfolders"
[[ $sb_command_passed =~ $regexMatch ]]
param1=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
echo $param1
```

Now while passing the following to the script:

```
find every file matching "search" in this folder and subfolders
```

It isn't returning **search** as the matched parameter. If this succeeds, I'd like to pass a regex in there :

```
find every file matching "\s.+[^&*]" in this folder and subfolders
```

and get **\s.+[^&*]** in return. Can you help me out with this?

Comment: Why are you passing the string `"find every file matching "\s.+[^&*]" in this folder and subfolders"` and not just what you *actually* want - the `"\s.+[^&*]"`?

Comment: Just remove the single quotes: `regexMatch="^find every file matching (.*) in this folder and subfolders"`

Comment: @Tomalak well, that actually is the problem, I need to pass the entire sentence to my script.

Comment: @morgano yes, I know it does match and return the capture your way, however that isn't what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you simply have your quotes the wrong way round. This works:

```
$ regexMatch='^find every file matching "(.*)" in this folder and subfolders'
$ sb_command_passed='find every file matching "\s.+[^&*]" in this folder and subfolders'
$ [[ $sb_command_passed =~ $regexMatch ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
\s.+[^&*]
```

The single quotes go around the whole string and the double quotes go around the part you're trying to capture.

Comment: can I not do something with the double quotes in it? Maybe escape a sequence?

Comment: do you mean that you would like to be able to include double quotes in the pattern?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean.